# Problem with accessing JBoss EAP 7.3 admin console on a Windows 10 machine

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Attempting to open the JBoss EAP 7.3 admin console ends with blank white page with no errors in cmd terminal window.

Steps I did:

- unzip jboss-eap-7.3.0.zip
- run c:\AppServers\jboss-eap-7.3\bin\add-user.bat
- update admin user and enter valid password
- start local server c:\AppServers\jboss-eap-7.3\bin\standalone.bat
- open http://127.0.0.1:9990/console/index.html
- result blank page

DevTools Console output

```
hal-0.js:10804          GET http://127.0.0.1:9990/management 401 (Unauthorized)
hal-0.js:10803          GET http://127.0.0.1:9990/keycloak/adapter/wildfly-console 404 (Not Found)
hal-0.js:10811 11:30:43.262 ERROR o.j.h.c.b.endpoint.EndpointManager       Keycloak adapter 'http://127.0.0.1:9990/keycloak/adapter/wildfly-console' doesn't exist - status: 404
hal-0.js:5706          POST http://127.0.0.1:9990/management 401 (Unauthorized)
hal-0.js:10811 11:30:43.281 ERROR o.j.h.c.bootstrap.HalBootstrapper        Bootstrap error: Authentication required.
```

DevTools Network panel output

```
index.html  304 document    Other   95 B    8 ms    
polyfill.min.js 200 script  index.html  (memory cache)  0 ms    
external.min.js 200 script  index.html  (memory cache)  0 ms
hal.nocache.js  200 script  index.html  (memory cache)  0 ms
hal.min.css 200 stylesheet  index.html  (disk cache)    5 ms    
BD3BC5E1B9793E31D587DA5F8EC8FBDE.cache.js   200 script  hal.nocache.js:10   (disk cache)    36 ms   
OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2  200 font    hal.min.css (memory cache)  0 ms    
management  401 xhr hal-0.js:10804  429 B   4 ms    
worker.js   200 javascript  Other   (disk cache)    2 ms    
favicon.ico 200 x-icon  Other   (disk cache)    2 ms    
wildfly-console 404 xhr hal-0.js:10803  206 B   3 ms    
pouchdb.min.js  200 javascript  worker.js:16    (disk cache)    3 ms
management  401 xhr hal-0.js:5706   773 B   4 ms
```

Same steps in home environment don't cause any issues.
I don't have any GET requests to keycloak/adapter/wildfly-console
I can open jboss console and login as admin.

The difference highly likely is in corporate security setup.
And I have to know exactly what to ask security department. Could you give me any idea what to look for?

Comment: Did you find the solution to the problem?

Comment: @GáborDANI I gave up. The organization implemented so paranoic firewall that I quit.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar looking problem which turned out to be an issue with digest authentication in the browser (Edge & Chrome); most likely due to some corporate policy.

Using an example from [this page](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The%20HTTP%20management%20API.html) I was able to use curl to interact with the management console, so I could confirm that it wasn't an issue with the server's config:

```
curl --digest -D - http://localhost:9990/management --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"operation":"read-resource", "include-runtime":"true" , "recursive":"true", "address":["subsystem","undertow","server","default-server"], "json.pretty":1}' -u admin:admin
```

[This superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/978255/chrome-45-does-not-display-authentication-dialog) is what got me onto the right track. In my case I was able to install Firefox, and that worked. If you're not able to use another browser your IT department may need to alter the [AuthSchemes registry value](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#AuthSchemes) so that Digest authentication works.